# How to find max number of thread in solaris

Tags: operating-system, solaris

How to get the max number of thread supported by Solaris application, as in linux we can find out by using command `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this question?

Comment: One application is died while thread creation, returning error `EAGAIN The  system  lacked  the  necessary resources to create another thread`.

Comment: Perhaps you need to examine other things first, rather than how many threads you could create. For instance - was the system sized correctly for the task? What restrictions were activated via old /etc/system settings? What tuning had been done? What did the application try to do?